need clarification on FLATPAK librewolf bookmark can't import
i just reformat my pc, install librewolf flatpak and trying to restore my bookmark data. but when i opened bookmark manager (ctrl+shift+o) and try to import bookmark data the file browser did not open. i also try through librewolf setting in the import browser data section and click select file but nothing come out. need clarification.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product & release details; you also mention flatpaks which aren't a Ubuntu default. What Ubuntu product/release are you using?

I noted this text "Suppose you want to use Firefox without the ability to sync using a Firefox account..." in this itsfoss article. Perhaps that is your issue? You can get help from Librewolf here
